# Actionscript 3 browser requirement

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently consider implement an application using actionscript 3. Minimum browser requirement is important to me because I can't assume most of my user will equipped with modern browser. I tried to google around the browser requirement for running actionscript, but didn't found something quite useful. Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ActionScript is not executed by the browser, it is executed by the Flash Player, notably player version 9 or higher for ActionScript 3.

As far as browser compatibility for the Flash Player, here are the Adobe specs for minimum Flash Player requirements: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/tech-specs.html. Note that those are the specs for version 11, and they require IE7 or higher - but if you are targeting Flash Player 9 (minimum for AS3), then you can easily run on IE6 and all other major browsers.

Overall, it's not something I'd be concerned with. Flash Player has been supported by all major browsers for quite a long time. Other than mobile browsers (phones and tablets), you'd be hard-pressed to find a desktop browser that doesn't support it (as long as the end user chooses to install the player, that is).

Comment: I should also bring up that the metro-version of IE on the upcoming Windows 8 won't support plugins, meaning no Flash. But I doubt that's applicable to this situation - I just mention it to be thorough.

Comment: `+1` I have access to analytics reports for large organisations with upward of 50,000 views per day and over 97% of viewers have at least Flash Player 9 installed.